# What is happening to Java Short with PostgreSequence?

Tags: jpa, sequence, short

Hey I wasnt expecting that. Im using JPA SequenceGenerator for my numeric primery keys, works out of the box. Hey but what happen to java shorts. When my entities have short ID then the sequence dont generate a value, instead it assign allways 0 what causes duplicate key. :S.

I just me, or you cant map a short to a sequence object? It create the sequece in the database but it doesnt appear to be calling nexval on it.

Im using: eclipselink 2.3, openjdk7, ubuntu oneiric amd64, eclipse.

HEre some code:

This works:

```
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="CategoriaDeportiva_SEQ")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "CategoriaDeportiva_SEQ", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1, sequenceName="CategoriaDeportiva_SEQ")
private int id;
```

This doesnt:

```
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="CategoriaDeportiva_SEQ")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "CategoriaDeportiva_SEQ", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1, sequenceName="CategoriaDeportiva_SEQ")
private short id;
```

Answer (score 0):

That is odd.  Do you get any errors in your logs, what SQL is logged if you set EclipseLink logging to finest?

It is either an issue with Postgres or with EclipseLink.
It could be some issue with binding a short in Postgres, to workaround this you could use an @Convert and @TypeConverter(dataType=Integer.class) on the @Id mapping to bind it as an int instead.

You could also try it on another database to confirm if it is a Postgres issue.

If it is an EclipseLink issue, please log a bug.

In general using a short as an Id is not a very good idea, it would be very easy to run out of Ids.  Even using int is not recommended, long is best.